# prevent second hard-drive from spinning up after standby

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, sleep-wake

I have a MacBook Pro with two harddrives, an SSD in the main slot and a larger, normal drive in place of the superdrive.

Because of power consumption and noise I managed to get my Mac to **not** automatically start and mount the second harddrive when booting up, but it still spins up the drive when waking up from hibernation / standby / sleep (don't know the correct terminology here).

Is there a way to prevent this? I have a script that ejects the disk, causing it to spin down. I guess I am looking for a postWakeup-hook of some sort to run it when the laptop wakes up.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a satisfying solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Running your script on wake up, with [Power Manager](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011/02/01/how-to-run-an-applescript-on-wake-up/), or using [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/), for instance, should do the trick.

There are, actually, different *sleep* modes, and knowing exactly which one you are using may help too, as **Sleeping** your Mac should not use the Hard Drive, the second disk should stay idle. [Here](http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/f/What-Really-Happens-When-You-Put-Your-Mac-To-Sleep.htm) is a brief explanation of what happens with each sleeping mode.

Comment: Thanks, will try this ASAP. I mean the sleepmode that consumes the least power, basically closing the lid, where the harddrives slow down and the light thingie at the front slowly pulsates. Will have to read your links.